# Most efficient way to find a 3rd Person singular pronoun, a noun and a verb in a sentence in spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

i have this code (I'm a newbie in Python) and it works fine, but i think my code is not efficient.
It checks out if a sentence contains a Third-Person Singular Pronoun (he, she or it), a noun and a verb:

```
def findNounVerbPronoun():
    countElements = 0
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp("Between traveling, working, and preparing to be a mother for the first time, she is a very busy woman.")
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
            countElements = countElements + 1
        if token.pos_ == "PRON" and token.morph.get("Person") == ["3"] and token.morph.get("Number") == ['Sing']:
            countElements = countElements + 1
        if token.pos_ == "VERB":
            countElements = countElements + 1
    if countElements == 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is it possile to find out if a sentence contains a verb, noun and a pronoun (in the third person singular) in an easier way than this way? I think that my code is not really pythonic. Thank you very much!

Comment: You will also sum up to 3 with 3 nouns ... wouldn't you`?

Comment: Pet peeve: `if countElements == 3: return True else: return False` can simplified to `return  countElements == 3`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work too:

```py
def findNounVerbPronoun():
    countElements = 0
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp("Between traveling, working, and preparing to be a mother for the first time, she is a very busy woman.")
    for token in doc:
        print(token)
        if token.pos_ in {"NOUN","VERB"} or token.pos_ == "PRON" and token.morph.get("Person") == ["3"] and token.morph.get("Number") == ['Sing']:
            countElements+=1
            if countElements==4:
                return False #not necessary to continue
    return countElements==3
```